# Tkinter screen wipe, specific

Tags: python, tkinter

Hello there Im new to the forum.

I have lots of experience with python but none with tkinter.

This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *


def Done():
     celEntry = celTempVar.get()
     print(str(celEntry))
     f = open("Name", "w")
     f.write(str(celEntry))
     f.close()

def Yes():


     celEntry = Entry (mainframe, width = 10, bd = 5, textvariable = celTempVar)
     celEntry.grid(row = 3, column = 1, pady = 10, sticky = NW, padx = 125 )

     titleLabel = Label (mainframe, text = "Enter Name", font = ("Arial", 12, "bold"), justify = LEFT)
     titleLabel.grid(row = 2, column = 1, columnspan = 3, pady = 10, padx = 20)

     DoneButton = Button (mainframe, text = "Done", font = ("Arial", 8, "bold"), relief = RAISED, bd=5, justify = CENTER, highlightbackground = "red", overrelief = GROOVE, activebackground = "black", activeforeground="blue", command = Done)
     DoneButton.grid(row = 4, column = 1, ipady = 8, ipadx = 12, pady = 5, sticky = NW, padx = 55)




###MAIN###
root = Tk()
root.title("Text Adv")
mainframe = Frame(root)
mainframe.grid()

celTempVar = StringVar()
celTempVar.set("")

titleLabel = Label (mainframe, text = "Text adventure", font = ("Arial", 20, "bold"), justify = CENTER)
titleLabel.grid(row = 1, column = 1, columnspan = 3, pady = 10, padx = 20)


f = open("Name", "r")
Name = f.read()

if Name == "":
     celEntry = Entry (mainframe, width = 10, bd = 5, textvariable = celTempVar)
     celEntry.grid(row = 3, column = 1, pady = 10, sticky = NW, padx = 125 )

     titleLabel = Label (mainframe, text = "Enter Name", font = ("Arial", 12, "bold"), justify = LEFT)
     titleLabel.grid(row = 2, column = 1, columnspan = 3, pady = 10, padx = 20)

     DoneButton = Button (mainframe, text = "Done", font = ("Arial", 8, "bold"), relief = RAISED, bd=5, justify = CENTER, highlightbackground = "red", overrelief = GROOVE, activebackground = "black", activeforeground="blue", command = Done)
     DoneButton.grid(row = 4, column = 1, ipady = 8, ipadx = 12, pady = 5, sticky = NW, padx = 55)

else:
     titleLabel = Label (mainframe, text = "Start new game?", font = ("Arial", 12, "bold"), justify = LEFT)
     titleLabel.grid(row = 2, column = 1, columnspan = 3, pady = 10, padx = 20)

     DoneButton = Button (mainframe, text = "Yes", font = ("Arial", 8, "bold"), relief = RAISED, bd=5, justify = CENTER, highlightbackground = "red", overrelief = GROOVE, activebackground = "black", activeforeground="blue", command = Yes)
     DoneButton.grid(row = 3, column = 1, ipady = 8, ipadx = 12, pady = 5, sticky = NW, padx = 55)

     DoneButton = Button (mainframe, text = "No", font = ("Arial", 8, "bold"), relief = RAISED, bd=5, justify = CENTER, highlightbackground = "red", overrelief = GROOVE, activebackground = "black", activeforeground="blue", command = Done)
     DoneButton.grid(row = 4, column = 1, ipady = 8, ipadx = 12, pady = 5, sticky = NW, padx = 55)

root.mainloop()
```

So what i would like is to whipe the screen when Yes() is run.

Simple but with all other answers I dont really understands.

If you could implement a wipe function into my code that would be great.

Atm I am just experimenting with other peoples code so thats why variable names are stuff like CeltoFar or something.

If you dont understand I mean wipe as in remove all widgets from the gui, or remove a specific widget.

Please dont leave any hate!

Thanks

And yes i like new paragraphs :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can destroy a widget, which will remove it from the screen. Just call the `destroy` method on the widget. When you destroy a widget, all of its child widgets will also be destroyed. So, for example, if you want to destroy all widgets in a frame, you only have to destroy the frame.

If you simply want to remove them from the screen rather than destroy them, you can call the `grid_remove`, `grid_forget`, `pack_forget` or `place_forget` widgets, depending on how you put them on the screen.

And, of course, instead of deleting them or removing them from the screen, you can also reset the value of the widget. How you do that depends on the type of widget, but all widgets can be reconfigured without being destroyed.

Comment: Thanks but how would i do this? I dont understand where i would put  the destroy function.

Comment: I type:    DoneButton.destroy() in Yes and it comes up with a error:

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1475, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "G:\Python\Gui.py", line 27, in Yes
    DoneButton.destroy()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'DoneButton' referenced before assignment

Comment: @user2921254: if you have lots of experience with python you should know what that means, because this is just a standard python error; it has nothing to do with tkinter per se. You're doing `DoneButton.destroy()` before you define what `DoneButton` is. You have to create an object before you can call a method on it.